# What's the difference between "instabil" and "unstabil"?

Tags: difference, connotation

**Question**

What's the difference between `instabil` and `unstabil`?

**Elaboration**

I always use `instabil`, but hear other people also use `unstabil`.

I assumed `unstabil` was wrong, but Duden has an entry for it: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unstabil

Duden has also an entry for `instabil`: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/instabil

Some Internet sources say that `unstabil` is used for "unstable constructions / buildings" but I feel like `instabil` goes perfectly well in that context, too.

Can anybody shine a light on the differences in connotation if there are any?

**Statistics**

If you enter `unstabil` into Google, Google's "Did you mean" feature suggests `instabil`. https://www.google.ch/?#q=unstabil

Also, Google Trends says that `instabil` is used way more often: http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=instabil%2C%20unstabil&cmpt=q

Comment: Just like "unstable" and "instable", but the other way around.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### [un-](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Praefixe/un.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules111712)

This is a very common German adjective prefix used to negate the adjective's meaning. Etymology shows that [`un-`](https://www.dwds.de/wb/un-) is a prefix of very old origin which can also be found in English (*unstable*). Whilst grammatically correct, it is not always idiomatic to use it on any adjective (children may do so):

> unrund, unbedeutend, undurchsichtig (correct) *vs.* unrot, unleise, unlebendig  (unidiomatic but not incorrect)

There are many borderline cases where the prefix `un-` is used but the result may be somewhat *"unschön"*. I would count *unstabil* as belonging to this category.

### [in-](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-A/Praefixe-F/in.html?MenuId=WordFormationRules111810)

Amongst other foreign adjective prefixes `in-` like `un-` is used to negate the meaning. This prefix is preferably used for loanwords from Latin (or Greek). We do find its counterpart in the English language too (*instability probably derived from instable*).

> intolerant, indiskret, indirekt

It can not be used with German adjectives that are not loanwords. Note that the spelling may change to *im-, il-, ir-* on adjectives starting with the letters *l, m,* or *r* (immateriell, illegal, irreal).

There is little to no difference in the meaning of a negated adjective if we had used *un-* or *in-* but using a Latin prefix on a Latin loanword is considered better style.

Comment: I don't think *instable* is legal in English, actually.

Comment: @Ingmar: it's certainly not used as much as it's noun *instability* - but I did not want to mix this up here, and I wanted to show that the issue is not only a German related one.

Comment: I agree, in principle. It's just that while Duden (grudgingly?) allows *instabil*, of all the English dictionaries at my disposal only the OED mentions *instable*, not without adding "Now rare."

Comment: Might as well chime in here as a native (US) English speaker: I wouldn't use "instable", but rather unstable exclusively. However, I think the point is best made with the noun "instability", as Takkat points out.

Comment: @Milchgesicht: native vote rules here :)

Answer (score 6):

It's pretty much a matter of personal preference. I think that, historically, *unstabil* was considered wrong but Duden probably added it at some point simply because it was frequently used. In a general context, at least, there is no difference in meaning; I would (and do, for what it's worth) use *instabil* exclusively.

Comment: First I was like: no `unstabil` isn't a correct word but after having looked it up in the Duden I had to accept that it's a correct word. Weird..

Answer (score 5):

They are [synonyms](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/instabil), meaning they can be used interchangeably.

However, `instabil` is used more often. [Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unstabil%2Cinstabil&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cunstabil%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bunstabil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUnstabil%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cinstabil%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Binstabil%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BInstabil%3B%2Cc0) is a visualization using Google's Ngram Viewer.

[image]

Comment: They are synonymous, indeed, but my _Sprachgefühl_ wants to see tiny differences in meaning: an _instabil_ construct once was _stabil_, whereas an _unstabil_ one has always been that way.

Answer (score 0):

„Instabil“ ist die eigentlich korrekte Form, die heute in gehobener Sprache verwendet wird, eher von gebildeter Bevölkerung mit evtl. lateinischen Grundkenntnissen. Unstabil   wird eher umgangssprachlich verwendet.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Gibt es zufällig für diese Ansicht auch sowas wie einen Etymologie-Eintrag in einem (Online-)Lexikon? Der duden.de-Eintrag des OPs macht dazu leider keine weiteren Angaben - außer dass bei instabil der Eintrag deutlich länger ist.